# How do I change the language in Medal of Honor 2010 for PC?

Tags: medal-of-honor

I bought the retail **English** version of Medal of Honor 2010 (everything on the box is only English).

When I installed the game, the installation was in French and when I start MoH, everything is French (dialogues, text, UI). I run Windows 7 Ultimate English but my keyboard and locales (date format, currency...) are French-Canadian. I guess the installer detects (badly) the language and then setup the game based on the detection.

My problem is that you can't change the language from the UI of the game/installer. I used the live help from EA and the guy told me to uninstall, download the online installer and reinstall (what's the point of buying retail if I have to download 4+GB for the same game!?). I then opened a ticket and it got closed without any update from them (nice work EA).

It took nearly an hour to install the game. I don't feel to uninstall/reinstall everything based on a wild guess.

Anyone know a way (registry key, INI file entry, anything) to change the language in Medal of Honor 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hkey_Local_Machine/software/wow6432node/electronic arts/electronic arts/medal of honor

change the language to English and locale to int (can't remember which one worked for me)

Comment: Language = English / Locale = en_EN did it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the game with System Locale and Format (in Region and Language control panel) set to English.